# How to return multiple value from a pytest fixture with scope = session

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django, django-fixtures

I have created pytest fixture in conftest.py for creating user and auto login

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def api_client():
   from rest_framework.test import APIClient
   return APIClient()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
@pytest.mark.django_db
def create_user():
    def make_user(**kwargs):
        # employee = e_ge_employee.objects.create()
        kwargs['password'] = 'strong-test-pass'
        if 'username' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['username'] = 'test-user'
        # if 'employee' not in kwargs:
        #     kwargs['employee'] = employee
        return e_ge_user.objects.create_user(**kwargs)
    return make_user

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
@pytest.mark.django_db
def auto_login_user(api_client, create_user):
    def make_auto_login():
        print("_+==--=-=-=-===--=-=-==----=-=-=-=")
        user = create_user()
        api_client.login(username=user.username, password='strong-test-pass')
        return api_client, user
    return make_auto_login
```

Now how to call the get, post method using API client and how to access user in multiple test cases written in test_views.p

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestViews:

    def test_generate_token_views_post(self,auto_login_user):
        **"To be Answered"**
        assert True == True

    def test_generate_token_views_post2(self,auto_login_user):
        **"To be Answered"**
        assert True == True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `make_auto_login()` in the `fixture`, this will execute the function and return `api_client` and `user`. After that in the tests `auto_login_user` will be a tuple with the values

`conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
@pytest.mark.django_db
def auto_login_user(api_client, create_user):
    def make_auto_login():
        print("_+==--=-=-=-===--=-=-==----=-=-=-=")
        user = create_user()
        api_client.login(username=user.username, password='strong-test-pass')
        return api_client, user
    return make_auto_login()
```

`test_views.py`

```
class TestViews:

    def test_generate_token_views_post(self, auto_login_user):
        api_client, user = auto_login_user
        assert True

    def test_generate_token_views_post2(self, auto_login_user):
        api_client, user = auto_login_user
        assert True
```

Comment: This solution is working but problem with this solution is that everytime it is calling auto_login_user fixture and is creating new user everytime, 
Could you suggest something ?

Comment: @KritikAlawat It doesn't happen to me and I can't reproduce. In the current structure `auto_login_user` should run once.

Comment: as per your solution if I use this api_client, user = auto_login_user I get error TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable.
And if i use api_client, user = auto_login_user() this auto_login_user will run evertime.
Could you please look into this ?

Comment: @KritikAlawat you probably didn't change `auto_login_user` return to `return make_auto_login()`

Comment: Sorry I missed that but after changing it to make_auto_login() it is giving me an error of 
RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
I haven't changed anything else. Could you explain why this is happening ?